# How to reference Google Cloud Storage image with "img src" (link direct to the image)

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Say I do this

`./gsutil cp /home/blah/blah/post-images/google/cube.jpg gs://(bucket-name)/google/cube.jpg`

The image is supposed to be here

`<img src="https://console.developers.google.com/storage/(bucket-name)/google/cube.jpg`

(as per https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/access-public-data) but it doesn't work...

That URL is fine if you want to see the image in the "bucket" and browse the bucket's directory structure, but useless if you want to link to the image directly.

I can go here [https://console.developers.google.com/m/cloudstorage/b/(bucket-name)/o/google/cube.jpg](https://console.developers.google.com/m/cloudstorage/b/%28bucket-name%29/o/google/cube.jpg) to link directly to the image, BUT is this "/m/cloudstorage/b/" an arbitrary location or can I always find my images in there?  Also what is "/o/" that's not a subdirectory I created.  Are these random letters of the alphabet or is there a method to Google's madness or is it always "/o/" ?

In short, what's the correct way to directly link to my Google Cloud Storage images?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That URL is for the developer's console UI.

See [Request URIs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-uris) for a list of access points.

You probably want:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/bucketname/google/cube.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you, I submitted a recommendation to Google to add this to https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/access-public-data

Comment: @PJBrunet - the [Access Public Data](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/access-public-data) page has been updated.

Comment: Great, and now I see the links in the dev console listings too.