# Google Cloud Storage management with Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage

I'm using pliablematter simple-cloud-storage to manage uploads/downloads of files using Google Cloud Storage. But I'm not able to make it work, there's a property file with this content:

```
project.id=0000000000
application.name=Application Name
account.id=0000000000@developer.gserviceaccount.com
private.key.path=/var/key
```

I know my project.id, aplication name and account id but what should I put in private key path?? I generated and downloaded the service account private key but no matter which path location I always get `java.io.FileNotFoundException`

Moreover, where should I save private keys in Android applications?

Github project https://github.com/pliablematter/simple-cloud-storage

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by copying the private key to an internal storage folder, then I put the path location in private.key.path

Don't know if this is the right way but it worked for me.

Comment: hey do you know how to get the direct image URL from the cloud storage to display the images in list view?

Comment: @LOG_TAG I've not achieved that yet but I recommend you to use this [library](https://github.com/pliablematter/simple-cloud-storage). Its very well explained and yes you can get a list of files from your cloud storage. Hope works for you

Comment: I'm not sure if its possible to get a public URL from GCS files but one way should be downloading files to an internal storage and then show them in a list view.

Comment: Thanks for the info. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485102/how-to-reference-google-cloud-storage-image-with-img-src-link-direct-to-the-i

Answer (score 0):

Here are the changed which you need to make after using [that example](https://github.com/pliablematter/simple-cloud-storage) to make it functional in android.

- Download the **private_key.p12** file from Google Console and put in Assets.
- Save your **cloudstorage.properties** file in Assets as well.

Now make these method changes in `CloudStorage` class.

```
private Properties getProperties() throws Exception {

        if (properties == null) {
            properties = new Properties();
            AssetManager manager = context.getAssets();
            InputStream stream = manager.open("cloudstorage.properties");
            try {
                properties.load(stream);
            } catch (IOException
                    e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "cloudstorage.properties must be present in classpath",
                        e);
            } finally {
                if (stream != null)
                    stream.close();
            }
        }
        return properties;
    }

    private Storage getStorage() throws Exception {

        if (storage == null) {

            HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

            List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
            scopes.add(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL);

            Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                    .setServiceAccountId(
                            getProperties().getProperty(ACCOUNT_ID_PROPERTY))
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(getPrivateKeyFile())
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes).build();

            storage = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
                    credential).setApplicationName(
                    getProperties().getProperty(APPLICATION_NAME_PROPERTY))
                    .build();
        }

        return storage;
    }

    private File getPrivateKeyFile() {
        File f = new File(context.getCacheDir() + “/my_private_key.p12");
        if (!f.exists())
        try {

            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(“private_key.p12");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
                fos.write(buffer, 0, read);

            fos.flush();
            is.close();
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("FILE", "FETCHED FILE:: " + f.getAbsolutePath() + " with data: " + f.length());
        return f;
    }
```

Comment: * Make sure you have Write File Permission granted, Internet permission on in manifest and Use AsyncTask or any similar class to call these methods at runtime.

Comment: where can we get "private_key.p12". Actually we have ".ppk" file only. How Can we use it?

Comment: Yes, please use the PPK file. It was a P12 file before but now Google gives PPK file.